# How to reproduce functionality for LW and SW in MIPS32 with an ALUSrc stuck-on-0 fault

Tags: mips, mips32

ALUSrc is stuck on 0. What are series of alternate MIPS operations which would reproduce the functionality of LW and SW in this situation?

I'm new to MIPS, so apologies ahead of time if I get some things wrong here. In this hypothetical situation, ALUSrc is stuck on 0, preventing immediate values from being read into the ALU. Naturally this breaks most I-type operations, including LW and SW. The problem calls for me to create alternative assembly code with existing MIPS instructions which reproduces the functionality of each command.

I'm not sure how to get the immediate value into the processor at all. I imagine there's options with Boolean operations and addition, but I haven't been able to figure it out. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:
There are probably many ways to produce a simple 1 or -1 constant, which can then be used to produce any other constant.  The following code sequence will produce a `1` whenever needed:

```
   jal dummy           # puts address of jal+4 into $ra
dummy:
   sltu $v0, $0, $ra   # sets $v0=1 b/c we know that $ra > 0
```

Starting with one constant we can shift, add, subtract, or, etc.. to create other constants.  1 shifted left by 10 gives us 1024, for example.  (The shift amount is an immediate but [10:6] and so isn't affected by your hypothetical issue.)

---

Ok, now, if the ALUSrc control signal is stuck on 0 then the ALU will always receive the Read Register 2 data read value.

*The idea then is to use this together with the fact that the hardware is always doing something even when inappropriate for a given instruction, like `LW`.*

*Effectively, the stuck `ALUSrc` control signal turns certain ALU-oriented I-type instructions into R-Type instructions — this gives us a `lw rt, (ra,rb)`, where the effective address is `ra+rb` rather than `ra+sxt(imm)`.  (Branches use the 16-bit immediate field but are not affected by this control; shifts use a 5-bit immediate also not using this control.*

This means, for example, that if you put a register number in [15:11] of the immediate field, the ALU will receive that register's value (instead of the immediate).

So, for one, we can use an immediate value [15:0] of all zeros in an `LW`, and that immediate will have all zeros for [15:11], which — with a stuck ALUSrc — will source $0 (which holds zero) to the ALU.  That means we can do some basic load instructions with a zero offset.

---

By computing an immediate plus a base and then using an `lw`/`sw` with offset of zero then we can simulate an arbitrary load or store.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering! I understand how this can be used for loading with a zero offset (using $0), and I get that you can make constants with shifts and boolean operations. I'm not sure how I would create a lw/sw instruction with an arbitrary offset other than 0, since you would have to do addition with the immediate value... Sorry if I'm missing something obvious. How would I compute an "immediate plus a base" for an arbitrary offset without using, say, addi, which would of course be broken in this situation?

Comment: I don't know what I was thinking with the XOR thing; I've updated with another code sequence to make a `1` (for use in constructing any other constant).